# Solving a ODE from a diffeomorphism numerically

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, numerical-methods, lie-groups

This is a follow up from

[Example of a diffeomorphism on  $\mathbb{R}^{3}$onto itself (or cube onto itself)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1938387/example-of-a-diffeomorphism-on-mathbbr3-onto-itself-or-cube-onto-itself)

And

[Problem getting a diffeomorphism work on  $\mathbb{R}^{3}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1943544/problem-getting-a-diffeomorphism-work-on-mathbbr3)

**In short:** I am trying to get a diffeomorphism of the cube onto itself. The reason I want this is because I want a transformation of the cube that I can transform back, and I need to know the exact transformation, not an approximation. However, I'd be happy to have a numerical solution of a grid on the cube, as long as the solution on those points is exact.

I tried getting a analytic function, but the one I have chosen seems to have no ODE solution.

What I want is a solution to (or any other arbitrary diffeomorphism of the cube onto itself):

\begin{align*}
V(x,y,z) = \bigl(
  &\sin(x \cdot \pi/L)\sin(y \cdot \pi/L)\sin(z \cdot \pi/L),\\
  &\sin(x \cdot \pi/L)\sin(y \cdot \pi/L)\sin(z \cdot \pi/L),\\
  &\sin(x \cdot \pi/L)\sin(y \cdot \pi/L)\sin(z \cdot \pi/L)\bigr),
\end{align*}
being $L$ the length of the cube.

$$
\frac{d}{dt} h(x,y,z,t)= V(x,y,z).
$$

I need to solve $h$ for $t$ and $-t$ (read the first question for more insight). Or in other words, I need to find the inverse transformation. If I am given a grid on the "deformed" space, I need to find those points in the original cube.

However I have no idea how to do this. I am using MATLAB, if that helps to find a numerical solution.

Comment: The second reference gives us the message "This site can’t be reached".

Comment: @HandeBruijn fixed